# Nuxt error page not showing on production

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app ("nuxt": "2.15.8") and I need to create a `404` page.

Reading the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views/#error-page) I added the `layouts/error.vue` content:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>An error occurred</p>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Back to home</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    // Do not need it, I only need the 404 page
    // props: ['error'],
  }
</script>
```

With `nuxt.config.js` having:

```js
target: 'static'
```

And it works fine in dev mode (`yarn dev`). However when I build the app (`yarn generate`) and move the content to production it shows the default browsers page:

[image]

Which makes sense because the `yarn generate` doesn't create the 404.page:

```
➜  dist git:(master) ✗ la
total 44K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo foo 4,4K pro  16 14:39 200.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo foo 8,5K pro  16 14:39 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo foo 4,4K pro  16 14:39 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo foo    0 pro  16 14:39 .nojekyll
drwxrwxr-x 3 foo foo 4,0K pro  16 14:39 _nuxt
```

How to fix it so the production shows the 404 page? Thanks

Comment: Does you project work if you upload [it here](https://app.netlify.com/drop)?

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt doesn't create a default `404.html` page, cause it's a webapp, if there's an error the default fallback page is page 200.html, if you want to change the 200.html to 404.html you need to add:

```js
generate: { fallback: '404.html' },
```

In your `nuxt.config.js`.

But this is not at all, in some server you need to redirect to the right 404 page.

Comment: You can also use `fallback: true` as shown in [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#fallback).

Comment: I've created a '_.vue' file in my pages directory to handle 404 not found  error. Can you please tell me if it's ok or I should avoid it and use another solution instead?

Comment: It depend, in this way (not so elegant) you can say to the user "hey bro page don't exist" but to Google you always say http 200 code